# Tensorflow 2.0 and image processing

Tags: image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm just converting some code to tensorflow v2, but i'm facing an issue.
I used to use some tf.contrib.image functions in tensorflow v1 (dense_image_warp and rotate). I don't know how to replace them in v2. 
Those functions are not part of the tf.image module.

The tf_upgrade_v2 script can't convert those methods.

Does someone know how to replace them to be v2 compatible ?

Thank you

Comment: Consider adding some code. Contrib module won't be included in 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the image processing functions that were historically housed in `tf.contrib` have been migrated to other locations in TensorFlow 2.0. `dense_image_warp` and `rotate` are now part of the [`tfa.image`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/image) module in TensorFlow Addons.